# MultiDimensional arrays output

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am currently learning PHP and I am stuck with this problem while testing foreach with multi-dimensional arrays.
Here is my array:

```
     $employees = array(
 'Josh' => array(
        'age'=>'55',
        'salary'=>'105,000',
        'hobbies'=> array('none')
 ),
 'John' => array(
        'age'=>'45',
        'salary'=>'125,000',
        'color'=>'red',
        'hobbies'=> array('none')
 ),
 'Jane' => array (
        'age'=>'25',
        'salary'=>'93,000',
        'hobbies'=> array ('fishing', 'flying')
 ) 
);
```

Whenever I try to output I always get an error of Array to string conversion or Invalid argument. Can somebody tell me how could I correctly output this multi-dimensional array using foreach?

If I do it this way, the data like 125,000, basically the value assigned to age and salary isn't written out.

```
  foreach($employees as $names_of_employees=>$data) {
        echo $names_of_employees.'<br>';
        foreach($data as $specifics=>$values) {
            echo $specifics.'<br>';
        }
        foreach($values as $hobbies) {
            echo $hobbies;
        }

    }
```

If I do it this way, then it writes out, but as well it writes out "Array" and array to string error:

```
foreach($employees as $names_of_employees=>$data) {
    echo $names_of_employees.'<br>';
    foreach($data as $specifics=>$values) {
        echo $specifics.$values.'<br>';
    }
    foreach($values as $hobbies) {
        echo $hobbies;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add code with your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
<?php
  $employees = array(
         'Josh' => array(
                'age'=>'55',
                'salary'=>'105,000',
                'hobbies'=> array('none')
         ),
         'John' => array(
                'age'=>'45',
                'salary'=>'125,000',
                'color'=>'red',
                'hobbies'=> array('none')
         ),
         'Jane' => array (
                'age'=>'25',
                'salary'=>'93,000',
                'hobbies'=> array ('fishing', 'flying')
         ) 
  );

  foreach( $employees as $names_of_employees => $data ){
            echo $names_of_employees.'<br>';
            echo "Salary: ".$data['salary'].'<br>';
            echo "Age: ".$data['age'].'<br>';

             if( isset($data['hobbies']) && !empty($data['hobbies']) ) {
                 echo "Hobbies: ";
                 foreach(  $data['hobbies'] as $hobbies ) {
                         echo $hobbies.'<br>';
                 }
             }
  }
```

Comment: Well I would like to output the code in a list form, e.g: John<br> Salary: XXXXXX <br> Age XX <br> Hobbies: X,X,X,X

Comment: Check updated answer, if this helps you don't forgot to accept it as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you explain me the purpose of the if as I had hobbies set for each array, and if my big fault was not echoing salary and age as $data['age,salary'] but giving them foreach keys/values?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want.

```
foreach( $employees as $name => $data ){
    echo $name;
    echo $data['age'];
    echo $data['salary'];
    // ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for array element 'John' you've got an extra item in the second dimension.  I believe this is ok in PHP but perhaps you have to account for this in the code you use to read the values out.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to convert an array to a string. The problem is caused by `hobbies` since it is an array. So in your `foreach` loop that goes through `$data` you need to check if it is an array or if the key is equal to `hobbies`.

```
foreach($employees as $names_of_employees=>$data) {
    echo $names_of_employees.'<br>';
    foreach($data as $specifics=>$values) {
        if(is_array($values)) { //or you could say if($specifics == 'hobbies')
            echo $specifics . ': ' . implode(',',$values) . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo $specifics . ': ' . $values . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```